# PPC emulator to run MacOSX 10.5

Tags: macos, leopard, powerpc

Is there any PPC emulator (for either Intel Macs or any Linux) which can run MacOSX 10.5 PPC?

My current research only points me to [PearPC](http://pearpc.sourceforge.net) and the latest post/release was from 2011. On the homepage, they say that they have support for MacOSX 10.3 with some caveats. Also, it doesn't seem to emulate a soundcard which is relevant for me. Some totally outdated forum posts are asking about MacOSX 10.5 but without any real answers, e.g. [here](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/36238-leopard-in-pearpc/) or [here](http://www.emaculation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6134).

Comment: If you se Snow Leopard then Tosetta will run many PPC programs - in general is there a specific reason to run 10.5 ?

Comment: I have only MacOSX 10.9. I'm developing applications and want to test if they run on MacOSX 10.5 PPC.

Comment: Might be simplest to get an old Mac :)

Answer (score 1):

To do a 100% accurate test your best bet would be to get an actual PowerPC Mac. Alternatively, you can install 10.6 (Server) in a Virtual Machine, which can test PPC Applications through Rosetta.